# AWS RDP problom

Tags: amazon-web-services, rdp

when I try to log in as Administrator and it's password I get a message saying:
"To sign in remotely you need the right to sign in through Remote Desktop Services ..."
Interestingly, it says "Other user", not "Administrator" just above this message. Screen shot of that message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwqy5k11tpjhapp/Screenshot%202017-02-26%2008.14.08.png?dl=0

Because I can only connect with RDP (as far as I know - limited knowledge) I am now stuck without the ability to remotely access my instance. Can anyone get me out of this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have built an EC2 Windows instance from a provided windows AMI. (not a home brew)

Confirm that you have selected a valid AWS key pair to be used to create the master account and hash the password.

Remember that you need to retrieve the password from the console, however it sounds like you are not even getting to being asked for the password.

Q.  Is this a stand alone machine or has it been joined to a Domain ?
I ask because that sounds like it could be a Windows Policy block (Domain or Local) not necessarily and AWS issue.

I will check back later incase you have new information

RL

Comment: I created new password after I had launched the instance. 
and used it for few days.
but today, When I put the password that happend.